# Kafka FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND often seen in logs

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Running Kafka 2.3.0, Kafka client 2.1.1, and my brokers keep outputting the following logs:

```
[2019-09-06 15:18:03,596] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=0, fetcherId=0] Node 0 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=1458702821, epoch=538): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND. (org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler)
[2019-09-06 15:21:11,145] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=1] Removed 0 expired offsets in 1 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-09-06 15:22:33,737] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=0, fetcherId=0] Node 0 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=1917353656, epoch=538): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND. (org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler)
[2019-09-06 15:27:03,768] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=0, fetcherId=0] Node 0 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=404608404, epoch=538): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND. (org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler)
[2019-09-06 15:31:11,145] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=1] Removed 0 expired offsets in 1 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-09-06 15:31:34,313] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=0, fetcherId=0] Node 0 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=1690401868, epoch=539): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND. (org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler)
[2019-09-06 15:36:04,404] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=0, fetcherId=0] Node 0 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=1167288700, epoch=538): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND. (org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler)
[2019-09-06 15:40:34,409] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=0, fetcherId=0] Node 0 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=2135343705, epoch=538): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND. (org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler)
[2019-09-06 15:41:11,145] INFO [GroupMetadataManager brokerId=1] Removed 0 expired offsets in 1 milliseconds. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager)
[2019-09-06 15:45:04,930] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=0, fetcherId=0] Node 0 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=1735853846, epoch=539): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND. (org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler)
[2019-09-06 15:49:35,018] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=0, fetcherId=0] Node 0 was unable to process the fetch request with (sessionId=599232284, epoch=538): FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND. (org.apache.kafka.clients.FetchSessionHandler)
```

What does having a lot of FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND indicate? What could be a way to remedy that?

Half of my consumer groups do not consume anything and produce logs containing a lot of `FETCH_SESSION_ID_NOT_FOUND` lines.

Comment: @Gary Russell Can you please answer this, even I'm seeing this error

Comment: What’s the exact question ?

Comment: I have seen the same error... What you have seen?

Comment: Unfortunately I never really solved the problem and somehow with the update of Kafka the problem disappeared!

Comment: Also it is not an error, not even a warning but info. So best ignore it unless u have a real problem

Comment: Do you how to restart consumer automatically upon failure?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments this was resolved by updating Kafka.

(As far as it was a problem at all for this user). If you have a problem with additional symptoms it is likely a different situation so please use a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the number of your consumer threads exceeds the number of partitions. In this case, you can use 'kafka-consumer-groups.sh' to list all your consumer groups and check if there are any partitions that have not been consumed.